# Convert multiple elements of a list into a matrix R

Tags: r, list, matrix

I've got a list, for example:

```
    [[1]]
              [,1]
[1,] -1.775291e-04
[2,] -1.267184e-04
[3,] -1.573868e-03
[4,]  4.157234e-02
[5,] -4.864003e-02
[6,]  2.316697e-05

[[2]]
              [,1]
[1,] -0.0010882973
[2,]  0.0009780598
[3,]  0.0003006506
[4,]  0.1579244926
[5,]  0.1655930418
[6,] -0.0006471336

[[3]]
              [,1]
[1,]  2.861335e-03
[2,] -3.259585e-05
[3,]  3.377353e-03
[4,]  1.224368e-02
[5,]  6.205352e-02
[6,] -3.028701e-04

[[4]]
              [,1]
[1,]  0.0023484525
[2,] -0.0007958971
[3,]  0.0038275408
[4,] -0.1705923272
[5,] -0.0706761005
[6,] -0.0004604092
```

I'd like to change this so that I have a matrix where each list becomes the first row of the data table, essentially I'd like to transpose each element of the list and then put them on top of one another so that I can handle them later.

Comment: Try `do.call(rbind,lapply(x,c))`, where `x` is your list.

Comment: Hey thanks, that's great. If you don't mind, could you help explain what the "c" is in the lapply function? I don't quite know what it is!

Comment: `c` is maybe the most used function in R, you should know it. In this case, its purpose is to coerce the elements of the list, which are matrix objects, to vectors in such a way they can be `rbind`ed together.

Comment: In addition to nicola's precise description, you can read all about `c()` by entering `?c` in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `d` is your list:

```
d = list(matrix(rnorm(6), ncol = 1), matrix(rnorm(6), ncol = 1),matrix(rnorm(6), ncol = 1),matrix(rnorm(6), ncol = 1))
```

Then just use this:

```
t(sapply(d, c))
```

will result in a 4x6 matrix.

```
            [,1]       [,2]        [,3]       [,4]        [,5]       [,6]
[1,] -0.02910676 -0.8722619 -1.48340110 -1.9914850  0.80751174 -1.1062207
[2,] -0.38604263  0.6417695  0.02404823 -0.3484978 -1.03931644  1.0919702
[3,]  0.19229699  0.3389690  1.68451808  0.7688967  0.01010725 -0.3203104
[4,]  0.36910577 -0.4922259  0.81362335 -1.9770308  0.65197010  0.2063001
```

Answer (score 2):

If `L` is the list then:

```
t(simplify2array(L))
```

No packages are used.